# Dynamically create check boxes for given post titles in WPAlchemy

Tags: custom-field, wpalchemy

I'm using WPAlchemy to create meta boxes. What I want to do is to dynamically create a group of check boxes with post titles.

In other words, I want to replace `a`, `b` and `c` with the query of post titles.

```
<?php
$items = array('a', 'b', 'c');
while ($mb->have_fields('cb_ex', count($items))) {
    $item = $items[$mb->get_the_index()];
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state($item); ?>/> <?php echo $item; ?><br/>
    <?php
}
?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I came across this solution that may help anyone looking for a way to display post titles.

<?php $mb->the_field('icon-url'); ?>
<?php $selected = ' selected="selected"'; ?>
<select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
<option value=""></option>
<?php $terms = get_pages();
foreach ($terms as $taxindex => $taxitem) {
echo '<option value="'. $taxitem->ID .'"'; $thevalue = $taxitem->ID; if ($mb->get_the_value() == "$thevalue") echo $selected; ?>
<?php echo '>' . $taxitem->post_title .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>

Comment: Please add your solution as a real answer and mark the question as _answered_.